# How to call function by using defaults

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to call a function by using '_defaults' but it is not working.

Here 'employee_id' is the employee field of 'hr.payslip' and 'onchange_employee_id' is function.

```
def onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to, employee_id=False, contract_id=False, context=None):
   #my code#

_defaults = {
    'employee_id' : 'onchange_employee_id(date_from, date_to, employee_id, contract_id)'
}
```

Comment: if you use a function in the default it shouldnt be commented and should return the employee id

Comment: I tried without commented also but it is not working.

Comment: show the function code

Comment: Actually it is an existing ''onchange_employee_id" function so I override that function in xml file.but that onchange function is very important for me.

Comment: I will post that code as new question.

Comment: You are not returning an employee id in your function

Answer (score 0):

```
def onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to, employee_id=False, contract_id=False, context=None):
    empolyee_obj = self.pool.get('hr.employee')
    contract_obj = self.pool.get('hr.contract')
    worked_days_obj = self.pool.get('hr.payslip.worked_days')
    input_obj = self.pool.get('hr.payslip.input')

    if context is None:
        context = {}
    #delete old worked days lines
    old_worked_days_ids = ids and worked_days_obj.search(cr, uid, [('payslip_id', '=', ids[0])], context=context) or False
    if old_worked_days_ids:
        worked_days_obj.unlink(cr, uid, old_worked_days_ids, context=context)

    #delete old input lines
    old_input_ids = ids and input_obj.search(cr, uid, [('payslip_id', '=', ids[0])], context=context) or False
    if old_input_ids:
        input_obj.unlink(cr, uid, old_input_ids, context=context)


    #defaults
    res = {'value':{
                  'line_ids':[],
                  'input_line_ids': [],
                  'worked_days_line_ids': [],
                  #'details_by_salary_head':[], TODO put me back
                  'name':'',
                  'contract_id': False,
                  'struct_id': False,
                  }
        }
    if (not employee_id) or (not date_from) or (not date_to):
        return res
    ttyme = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_from, "%Y-%m-%d")))
    employee_id = empolyee_obj.browse(cr, uid, employee_id, context=context)
    res['value'].update({
                'name': _('Salary Slip of %s for the month of %s') % (employee_id.name, tools.ustr(ttyme.strftime('%B-%Y'))),
                'company_id': employee_id.company_id.id
    })

    if not context.get('contract', False):
        #fill with the first contract of the employee
        contract_ids = self.get_contract(cr, uid, employee_id, date_from, date_to, context=context)
    else:
        if contract_id:
            #set the list of contract for which the input have to be filled
            contract_ids = [contract_id]
        else:
            #if we don't give the contract, then the input to fill should be for all current contracts of the employee
            contract_ids = self.get_contract(cr, uid, employee_id, date_from, date_to, context=context)

    if not contract_ids:
        return res
    contract_record = contract_obj.browse(cr, uid, contract_ids[0], context=context)
    res['value'].update({
                'contract_id': contract_record and contract_record.id or False
    })
    struct_record = contract_record and contract_record.struct_id or False
    if not struct_record:
        return res
    res['value'].update({
                'struct_id': struct_record.id,
    })
    #computation of the salary input
    worked_days_line_ids = self.get_worked_day_lines(cr, uid, contract_ids, date_from, date_to, context=context)
    input_line_ids = self.get_inputs(cr, uid, contract_ids, date_from, date_to, context=context)
    res['value'].update({
                'worked_days_line_ids': worked_days_line_ids,
                'input_line_ids': input_line_ids,
    })
    return res
```